# Parse string to Float in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

How to covert string to float and do the addition operation in velocity template.

I have tried below stuff but did not work.

$Float = 0.0

$stringValue= "5.5"

$sum = 0.0

$sum = $sum + $Float.parseFloat($stringValue).

above stuff did not work even, "$Float.parseFloat($stringValue)" does not evalueted.

Answer (score 2):

just found the answers.

$textutils.parseFloat("5.5") can convert it to float.

Also, other way, 
In class file, 
Float f=5.6f; 
velocitytemplate.put ("floatVar",f);  //pass float variable to velocity template

In template, $f.parseFloat("5.5") will work.

Thank You.